# How to upload the file by requests module in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to upload file including x-auth-token.

But alerted 202 status code. What is problem?

URL

> https://ssproxy.ucloudbiz.olleh.com/v1/AUTH_2a776d59-9933-4c51-8d64-40830cffbf86/testfiles

File Path

```
files = {'upload_file':open('c:/users/administrator/desktop/key_list.txt', 'rb')}
```

headers(temporary token)

```
headers = {'X-Auth-Token':'AUTH_tk32fxxxxxxxxxxxxxx11f8a'}
```

python command:

```
>>> r = requests.put('https://ssproxy.ucloudbiz.olleh.com/v1/AUTH_2a776d59-9933-4c51-8d64-40830cffbf86/testzip', headers=headers, files=files)
>>> r
<Response [202]>
```

Comment: Try use `requests.post()` instead of `requests.put()`?

Comment: @KevinGuan um.... I used `requests.post()` But alerted 401 Error....So, I attempted `requests.put()`

Comment: Ah, possible because you should use `requests.post()` and `files = {'file': ....}` instead of `files = {'upload_file': ....}`. [The document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). If that also doesn't work, then I don't know why.

Comment: @KevinGuan  Let's try again :)

Comment: It's the same...... I depressed.....TT

Comment: `Error 202: The status code 202 indicates that server has received and understood the request and that it has been accepted for processing, although it may not be processed immediately.` For more info you can google it. Try to use `requests.Session`

Comment: @ManishGupta 
`r = requests.session()` , `s = r.put(url, files=files, headers=headers)` is output `print(s.text)
<html><h1>Accepted</h1><p>The request is accepted for processing.</p></html>` 
um...token is required to access the storage